# Variable doesn't change for another class

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

it happens that I'm making a bukkit arena plugin. I have an Arena class, with an enum for its status. The default status is Status.disabled. I have a method that I call on the on-Enable, which sets the arena to Idle Status. The Problem is that after I call the method for every arena, the arena appears as Disabled status again.
Here is part of my Arena class:

```
public class Arena {
    protected final Main main;

    public static enum Status{
        Idle,
        InLobby,
        InCountdown,
        InGame,
        Disabled;
    }

    private Status status = Status.Disabled;
    String name;
    Location lobby;
    Location start;
    Location end;
    List<Location> checkpoints = new ArrayList<Location>();
    int lives;
    int time;

    public Arena(Main main, String name, Location lobby, Location start, List<Location> checkpoints, Location end, int lives, int time)
    {
        this.main = main;
        this.name = name;
        this.lobby = lobby;
        this.start = start;
        this.checkpoints = checkpoints;
        this.end = end;
        this.lives = lives;
        this.time = time;
    }

    public void setStatus(Status statuss){
        this.status = statuss;
    }

    public final Status getStatus(){
        return status;
    }

    public final void onEnable(){
        this.status = Status.Idle;
        System.out.println(this.getStatus() + " Trying status set on OnEnable. This is made from an Arena class.");
        //The message above says status is Idle...
    }
}
```

Now, here's my onEnable method, which is on my Main class that extends to JavaPlugin:

```
ArenaManager manager;
public void onEnable(){
    PluginDescriptionFile pdfFile;
    pdfFile = this.getDescription();
    getLogger().info(pdfFile.getName() + pdfFile.getVersion() + " has been enabled!");
    manager = new ArenaManager(this);
    PluginManager pm = this.getServer().getPluginManager();
    pm.registerEvents(new events(this), this);
    getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true);
    saveDefaultConfig();
    for(Arena arena : manager.getAllArenas()){
        arena.onEnable();
    }
    getLogger().info("Plugin contains " + manager.getAllArenas().size() + " arena(s)!");
    foo();
}

public void foo(){
    for(Arena a : manager.getAllArenas()){
        System.out.println("foo " + a.getStatus());
    }
}
```

My method called "foo" checks the status for all arenas. The arenas appear as disabled when I try "foo". If this is useful, each arena is saved to a file, so to get all arenas, I use my arenamanager. The method from the arenamanager used in the onEnable is:

```
public List<Arena> getAllArenas(){
    List<Arena> arenas = new ArrayList<Arena>();
    File[] allfiles = new File(main.getDataFolder() + File.separator + "Courses" + File.separator).listFiles();
    assert allfiles != null;
    for(File f : allfiles){
        FileConfiguration con = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(f);
        String name = con.getString("Name");
        Arena a = getCourse(name);
        arenas.add(a);
    }
    return arenas;
}
```

I tried printing out the status as well from the PlayerInteractEvent (on a sign), but the arena still shows as disabled. Any idea on how to fix this? There are no errors on the console by the way. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Is it really the code you use? You seem to have an infinite recursion in `onEnable()`.

Comment: Where is the code for `getCourse()`? Depending on what `getCourse()` does, it looks like `getAllAreans()` is creating new `Arena` objects for the list that is returned. So everytime you call `getAllArenas()` you are creating new objects with the `Status` set to `Disabled`.

Comment: @PM77-1 Yes, that's what I'm using for the onEnable. I'm new to java, so am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @mdewitt This is the getCourse() method http://pastebin.com/mNc2aPU8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short:

The `status` variable does not change because you are not saving a reference to the `List` of `Arena` objects that are returned from `manager.getAllArenas()` that you use to set the `Status` on. You want to look at your code and find a way to save the state of the `Arena` object. There are a couple different ways to do this, but I am going to let you decide what is best for you.

The long explanation is below:

When you create an `Object` in Java, you must hold the object (reference it) somewhere if you want to keep using the same object and save the state.

In your `ArenaManager.onEnable()` method you call `manager.getAllArenas()` and set the `status` field on each `Arena` object to `Status.Idle`. Here:

```
public void onEnable(){
    ...
    for(Arena arena : manager.getAllArenas()){
        arena.onEnable();
    }
    ...
    foo();
}
```

The logic in `manager.getAllArenas()` is essentially

```
1. Create new List<Arena>
2. Get the name of all the Arena objects from File
3. For every File object, create a new Arena object
4. Add new Arena object to List created in step 1.
```

You do not save this list anywhere when you call `manager.getAllArenas()` in the `ArenaManager.onEnable()` method, so once you exit the for loop, all the `Arena` objects you set the `Status` on in the `Arena.onEnable()` method.

When you call `foo()` later in the `Arena.onEnable()`. You create a brand new list when you call `manager.getAllArenas()` again, so this list was not effected by your `for-loop` that set the `status` to `Status.Idle`